# Linear vs polynomial regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

If you have multiple dimensions to your data, where it is not possible to visualize 
them together, how to decide if your model should be linear or polynomial?

Comment: why would a *cost* function be linear? That would imply erring hugely one way would incur a negative cost...

Comment: @Glen_b I think the OP means to ask about whether the cost function should be linear or polynomial in the explanatory variables. E.g. is the model for $Y|X_1,X_2$, or $Y|X_1,X_1X_2,X_2$, or $Y|X_1^2,X_1,X_1X_2,X_2,X_2^2$, etc.

Comment: hi Pranay how many dimensions do you have?

Comment: @TooTone surely the model is not the same thing as the cost function. That would be bizarre. OP should clarify.

Comment: @Glen_b I see your point but in the machine learning course I did (Andrew Ng, coursera), the general approach was to produce a cost function that you could feed into an optimizer (or solve analytically in simple cases). In the first week, in linear regression we were taught that the cost function was $J(\theta_0,\theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum^m_{i=1}(h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2$, with $h(x)=\theta_0 + \theta_1x$. The line between a model and a cost function felt blurred in that course ($h(x)$ is the closest thing to a model in this example), so I can see where the OP might be coming from.

Comment: @Glen_n 
Glen_n you are right about where I am coming from, this question comes after the coursera course ..
When I meant cost function, it is actually the model.

Comment: @PranayWarke (you got my name wrong there; it won't notify me if you do that). Thanks for modifying your question; it makes more sense now.

Comment: @TooTone $h$ and $J$ are quite different things. $h$ is the model and is linear there; $J$ is the cost function and is *not linear*. You can't start confusing the two, or you end up asking nonsensical questions about linear cost functions... which takes us right back to where I first commented.

Comment: @Glen_b $h$ doesn't quite define the model does it? Isn't the model  $h(x) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x + W$, where $W \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, with $\sigma$ an additional parameter, or equivalently $Y|X=x \sim N(\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1, \sigma^2)$? I agree absolutely that there's a difference between the model and the cost function; but having done the same course as the OP, which blurred the boundaries, I can see where he was coming from in his initial formulation.

Comment: @TooTone You're correct that $h$ isn't the entirety of the model for *the data*. To be specific, $h$ is the model for the *mean*. It also doesn't pay to confuse those two things, but that's a different issue from the one at hand.

Answer (score 4):

If you did the same course as me, [Andrew Ng's machine learning course on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml), you will remember that it was suggested there to split the data into 3 parts.

1. Training set
2. Cross-validation set
3. Test set

Briefly, you fit each possible model to the training set. However you can't easily use the training set to decide which model is best, because additional terms in a model can only lead to a model fitting the training set better, with the possibility of *overfitting* (this is when the regression coefficients are "tuned" to noise in the training data). Rather you choose which model to use based on the error on the cross-validation set. Finally, you test how well the chosen model predicts using the test set.

If your model is highly dimensional, then it might be best to consider other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So finally it would be like a trial and error method, which in case of very high dimensions becomes infeasible

Comment: @PranayWarke Although there are ways to automate the process, yes it becomes infeasible. You also have to question whether a regression model (linear or polynomial) is suitable. On the whole you might prefer a parsimonious model with fewer parameters, especially if you don't have a large number of examples in your training set. So you could for example investigate whether some of your explanatory variables could be dropped, or choose a different kind of model altogether. You could try searching for "dimensionality reduction" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

@Pranay Just to add, one way to decide weather to fit a linear or a non-linear function is to do residual analysis. Starting from a linear function you need to find the residual values for all predicted values as :

Y<sub>actual</sub> - Y<sub>observerd</sub>

When you plot these values you can decide weather to fit a linear or a polynomial based how the residual values are scattered from the mean as:

[image]

If the values are randomly scattered then it may be safe to fit a linear function.

On the contrary if you can find a pattern in the residuals, then fitting a linear function is not going to work:

[image]

The above are the few among the many things you can do with residuals; they can be used to analyze large number of patterns in data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the above diagrams were taken from [link](http://docs.statwing.com/interpreting-residual-plots-to-improve-your-regression/). It also details more ways of using residuals.

Comment: do you have permission to use the diagrams? ... if you do (such as some license -- which you should indicate for each diagram) you should give proper credit to the person that originally made them in your post, since stackexchange requires proper attribution

Comment: @Glen_b check my my comment where I have added the link to the above diagrams and stated that the above diagrams were taken from that source as stackexchange does not let users under a certain reputation to add more than 2 links. Unless that is still not sufficient.